# How to use delegate to point a bunch of logs written to .txt to somewhere else? C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I just learned about delegates and the publisher/subscriber pattern, however I have been having some problem implementing them in my current code, mainly because Im not sure what should be assign to what(I shall explain this).

I have a class, example Class A. It is a library class that contains codes that write logs into .txt file. I would like to be able to take these logs and write them somewhere else, example another .txt file/TextBox/RichTextBox.

```
Class A
//Just a library class for log functions
//Declare and instantiate the delegate
public void delegate myDel(string message)      
public myDel customDel, customDel2

LogCategory(string category)
{
        //Bunch of codes that separates the log into category Info/Warn/Error
        WriteLog()
}

WriteLog()
{
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LogFilePath)
        //writes logs into .txt file1
       
}
```

then in a separate class

```
Class B
//This is the main program where all the logs are written
public void PrintLog(string message)
{ 
        Class A ca = new Class A();
        ca.LogCategory();
}


public void delegateTheLogs()
{
        //how do I use customDel to write the logs to another text file in a 
        //different directory         
}
```

The idea is that delegate is suppose to:

1. act as a pointer
2. allow the program to write logs to multiple destination at the same time

The question is what do I use customDel for and how do I use it catch the logs and write them somewhere?
I think this is an interesting topic, and if anyone knows how to do this, please help me figure this out.
Oh and Im not interested in using events, I know delegate and events are pretty common to use together.

Thanks

Comment: I think there might be a difference between what a delegate is and what you think it is. In essence it's a way to pass a method just like you would pass data. Your logger would take a delegate and call it and give it the string to log and the delegate (a method) does something with it. You change what is done by changing the code of the method you pass to the logging method (that calls the delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, here's an example. We have a class called FlexibleLogger that basically knows how to format stuff that it is given but it doesn't have any baked in ability to write the log data to anywhere, the idea being that the code that creates the logger also creates the routine that the logger will use to output:

```
public class FlexibleLogger{

    Action<string> _logWriterAction;

    public FlexibleLogger(Action<string> logWriterAction){
        _logWriterAction = logWriterAction;
    }
    
    public Log(string message){
        _logWriterAction($"{DateTime.UtcNow}: {Message}");
    }

    public Log(Exception ex){
        Log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This class doesn't know how to write a file, or console, or post the message to a web service, or email it, or put it in a rabbit queue etc.. all it knows how to do is formulate a log message provided into having a time at the start, or pull the message out of an exception(and then pass it to the method that puts a time at the start), and then call the Action (a neater way of declaring a delegate that takes arguments of various types and returns no value) passing in the message

The Action is some variable(able to be varied) method created by you

We might use it like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //it's a "local function", IMHO a neater way of providing a method that can be passed as an action
        void consoleWriterFunc(string f){
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        };
    
        //see the thing we pass as the Action parameter is a method/function, 
        //not a data item like a string, int, Person etc    
        var logger = new FlexibleLogger(consoleWriterFunc);
    
        //log will make a string like "12-Dec-2020 12:34:56: a"
        //and invoke the consoleWriterFunc, passing the string into it
        //in turn it prints to the console  
    logger.Log("a");
        

        //how about a logger that writes a file?
        void fileWriterFunc(string f){
            File.AppendAllText("c:\\temp\\some.log", f);
        };
    
        logger = new FlexibleLogger(fileWriterFunc);

        logger.Log(new Exception("something bad happened"));
    }
}
```

Doesn't have to be a local function, you can pass any method at all that takes a string and returns a void, as your `Action<string>`. It doesn't even have to be a method you wrote:

```
    var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        
    var logger = new FlexibleLogger(sw.Write);
        
    logger.Log("I'm now in the string writer" );
```

Microsoft wrote the method StringWriter.Write- it takes a strong, returns a void and calling logger.Log having passed the Write method of that stribgwriter instance means that the logger will Log into the stringwriter (a wrapper around a stringbuilder)

Hopefully this helps you understand that a delegate is "just a way to make a method into something you can pass as a parameter, just like anything else. They've been available for years, if you think about it, manifested as events. Microsoft have no idea what you want to do when you click a button, so they just have the button expose an event, which is really just a collection of delegates; a List of methods that the button should call when it's clicked.